# Connect to Azure Data Lake Gen 2 from local Spark job

Tags: java, azure, apache-spark, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I'm trying to connect from a local Spark job to my ADLS Gen 2 data lake to read some Databricks delta tables, which I've previously stored through a Databricks Notebook, but I'm getting a very weird exception, which I can't sort out:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: There is no primary group for UGI <xxx> (auth:SIMPLE)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getPrimaryGroupName(UserGroupInformation.java:1455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.<init>(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.initialize(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaTableUtils$.findDeltaTableRoot(DeltaTable.scala:94)
```

Searching around, I've not found many hints on this. One, which I tried was to pass the config "spark.hadoop.hive.server2.enable.doAs", "false", but it didn't help out.

I'm using io.delta 0.3.0, Spark 2.4.2_2.12 and azure-hadoop 3.2.0. 
I can connect to my Gen 2 account without issues through an Azure Databricks Cluster/ Notebook.

I'm using code like the folling:

```
 try(final SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("DeltaLake").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()) {
            //spark.conf().set("spark.hadoop.hive.server2.enable.doAs", "false");
            spark.conf().set("fs.azure.account.key.stratify.dfs.core.windows.net", "my gen 2 key");
            spark.read().format("delta").load("abfss://myfs@myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/Test");
}
```

Comment: is this issue resolved? If yes then can you please tell how you resolved it? I too am facing this same issue

Answer (score 0):

ADLS Gen2 requires Hadoop 3.2, Spark 3.0.0, and Delta Lake 0.7.0. The requirements are documented in https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-storage.html#azure-data-lake-storage-gen2

ADLS Gen2 Hadoop connector is only available in Hadoop 3.2.0, and Spark 3.0.0 is the first Spark version that supports Hadoop 3.2.

Databricks Runtime 6.x and older versions runs Hadoop 2.7 and Spark 2.4 but ADLS Gen2 Hadoop connector is backported to this old Hadoop version internally. That's why Delta Lake can work in Databricks without upgrading to Spark 3.0.0.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with Spark 3.0.0 Hadoop 3.2.0 and Delta 0.7.0

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with spark 3.1.1 Hadoop 3.2.0